# How to get response of GET request of web service and store it in a variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services

In my code I am sending a GET request to a server. In response of this I will get one URL which I want to store in a variable.

Can anyone help me regarding this? My code so far:

```
private void CreatePublicUrl()
{
    String CreatePublicUrl = String.Format("{0}/DataObjectServer/data/do/getproperties?cat=do&key=baseXmlPath&t={1}", base_url.Value, token);
    Debug.WriteLine("CreatePublicUrl==>" + CreatePublicUrl);
    HttpSyncRequest pub_url = new HttpSyncRequest();

    pub_url.sendGet(CreatePublicUrl, (urlResp) =>
    {
        var url = new Uri(urlResp);
        //      String urlresponse = JsonConvert.urlResp;
    });
}
```

Comment: what's `HttpSyncRequest`

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What is not working?

Comment: I am sending GET request. i want to know that how to get a response and the response will be url so i want to store it in a another variable

Comment: How to do so depends on the implementation of `HttpSyncRequest`, which isn't a BCL type. Where does that type come from?

Comment: Where resp. how are you sending the GET request? Have a look at the [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class in order to request data from a web server (from a specified URI).

Answer (score 0):

It seem you're trying to achieve it using some proprietary library. 
You can achieve the same using `HttpWebRequest`and `WebResponse`.

You can also do it using `WebClient` class as follows

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    String CreatePublicUrl = String.Format("{0}/DataObjectServer/data/do/getproperties?cat=do&key=baseXmlPath&t={1}", base_url.Value, token);
    using (Stream data = client.OpenRead(CreatePublicUrl))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data))
        {
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```